# On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ - Part II

Tags: number-theory, inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers, open-problem

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then we call $n$ an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must necessarily have the form $n = p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the *special prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently [Sorli](http://hdl.handle.net/10453/20034) conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  Dris conjectured that the inequality $p^k < m$ is true in his [M. Sc.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) [thesis](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), and [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) eventually produced a proof for the weaker inequality $p < m$.

Now, [recent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376268) [evidence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393738) suggests that $p^k < m$ may in fact be false.

**THE ARGUMENT**

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m$ is odd, then $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  Moreover, $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square** ([Dris and San Diego (2020)](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-4/33-38/)).

This implies that we may write
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$$
where $2^r \neq t$, $r \geq 2$, and $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

It is trivial to prove that $m \neq 2^r$ and $m \neq t$, so that we consider the following cases:

$$\text{Case (1):  } m > t > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (2):  } m > 2^r > t$$
$$\text{Case (3):  } t > m > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (4):  } 2^r > m > t$$
$$\text{Case (5):  } t > 2^r > m$$
$$\text{Case (6):  } 2^r > t > m$$

We can rule out Case **(5)** and Case **(6)**, and under Case **(1)** and Case **(2)**, we can prove that the inequality $m < p^k$ holds.

So we are now left with Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**:

Under both cases left under consideration, we have
$$(m - 2^r)(m - t) < 0$$
$$m^2 + 2^r t < m(2^r + t)$$
$$m^2 + (m^2 - p^k) < m(2^r + t)$$
$$2m^2 < m(2^r + t) + p^k.$$

Since we want to prove $m < p^k$, assume to the contrary that $p^k < m$.  We get
$$2m^2 < m(2^r + t) + p^k < m(2^r + t) + m < m(2^r + t + 1)$$
which implies, since $m > 0$, that
$$2m < 2^r + t + 1.$$

Here then is our question:

> **Will it be possible to derive a contradiction from the inequality
> $$2m < 2^r + t + 1,$$
> under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)** above, considering that $2m$ is *large*?  (In fact, it is known that $m > {10}^{375}$.)**

Comment: So $m$ is abundant ?

Comment: Do you have a proof that $m$ must be abundant, from the constraints given in my question, @RoddyMacPhee?  I would be interested to see it.

Comment: Misread thought $m
=2^rt$ for some reason then $2m<2^r+t+1$ would have implied it.

Comment: Assume to the contrary that $m = 2^r t$.  Then $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t = m$, which is equivalent to $m(m - 1) = m^2 - m = p^k$.  But this last equation contradicts $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  Hence, we are sure that $m \neq 2^r t$, @RoddyMacPhee.

Comment: Yeah still holds by multiplicative nature of sigma though... Just came up with wrong reasoning ...

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand, @RoddyMacPhee.  What *equation* / *inequality* follows from $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$ being multiplicative, where $x$ is a positive integer?

Comment: If $p\not\mid m$  then $\sigma(n)=\sigma(p^k)\sigma(m)$ and  since $\sigma(p^k)<2p^k$ we can at least say $sigma(m)>m$

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @RoddyMacPhee.  We are sure that $p \nmid m$, since $\gcd(p, m)=1$.  Also, $n = p^k m^2$, so what you have is actually the equation $2p^k m^2=2n=\sigma(n)=\sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)$.  Then we have the inequality $p^k < \sigma(p^k) < \frac{5p^k}{4}$, which finally gives $\frac{8m^2}{5}< \sigma(m^2) < 2m^2$.  (In particular, we also know that $m < \sigma(m) < 2m$, but that follows from the fact that $m > 1$ and $m$ is *deficient*, being a proper factor of the perfect number $n = p^k m^2$.)

Comment: $p^k\lt m$ is equivalent to $m\lt\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}$ which is better than $2m\lt 2^r+t+1$ since $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}\lt \dfrac{2^r+t+1}{2}$ is equivalent to $1\lt (2^r-t)^2$ which does hold.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  I would be interested to see the details of your proof for the biconditional
$$p^k < m \iff m < \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + 2^{r+2} t}}{2}.$$

Comment: Since $ p^k = m^2-2^r t$, we have $p^k\lt m$$\iff m^2-2^r t\lt m$$\iff m^2-m-2^rt\lt 0$$\iff m\lt\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}$

Comment: Please do write out your last comment as an answer, @mathlove, so that I can upvote.  Thanks!

Comment: I've just converted my comment into an answer in which I added more thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

---

- $p^k\lt m$ is equivalent to $$m\lt\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}\tag7$$ since we have$$\begin{align}p^k\lt m&\iff m^2-2^rt\lt m
  \\\\&\iff m^2-m-2^rt\lt 0
  \\\\&\iff m\lt\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}\end{align}$$

---

- $(7)$ is better than $2m\lt 2^r+t+1$ since
  $$\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}\lt \frac{2^r+t+1}{2}\tag8$$
  holds. 
  To see that $(8)$ holds, note that
  $$\begin{align}(2)&\iff \sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}\lt 2^r+t
  \\\\&\iff 1+2^{r+2}t\lt 2^{r+1}+2^{r+1}t+t^2
  \\\\&\iff (2^r-t)^2\gt 1
  \\\\&\iff |2^r-t|\gt 1\end{align}$$
  which does hold.

---

- We can say that $$\bigg(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}-t\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}-2^r\bigg)\lt 0\tag9$$
  since
  $$\begin{align}(9)&\iff \bigg(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}\bigg)^2-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}(t+2^r)+2^rt\lt 0
  \\\\&\iff \frac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}+2^{r+1}t}{2}-\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}(t+2^r)+2^rt\lt 0
  \\\\&\iff 1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}+2^{r+1}t-(1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t})(t+2^r)+2^{r+1}t\lt 0
  \\\\&\iff 2^{r+2}t-2^r-t+1\lt (t+2^r-1)\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}
  \\\\&\iff (2^{r+2}t-2^r-t+1)^2\lt (t+2^r-1)^2(1+2^{r+2}t)
  \\\\&\iff 2^{r + 2} t (2^r - t - 1) (2^r - t + 1)\gt 0
  \\\\&\iff (2^r-t)^2\gt 1
  \\\\&\iff |2^r-t|\gt 1\end{align}$$
  which does hold.

---

- It follows from $(7)(9)$ that if $p^k\lt m$ with $(m-t)(m-2^r)\lt 0$, then $$\min(t,2^r)\lt m\lt\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+2^{r+2}t}}{2}\lt \max(t,2^r)$$

Comment: Is it obvious to you that $\left|2^r - t\right| \neq 1$?  Would you mind sharing your proof for this assertion, @mathlove?  The proof for $\left|2^r - t\right| \neq 1$ that I know is complicated, and considers Case **(3)** and Case **(4)** separately.  It also uses ideas from this [closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263930), as well as methods from the [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.13652) mentioned there.

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : Suppose that $|2^r-t|=1$ which implies that $2^r,t$ are consecutive integers. Then, there is no integer $m$ such that $\max(2^r,t)\gt m\gt \min(2^r,t)$, a contradiction.

Comment: That is indeed a very simple and at the same time elegant proof for $\left|2^r - t\right| \neq 1$, @mathlove!  Thank you for sharing.  =)

Comment: Does your proof here for $p^k < m \implies |2^r - t| \neq 1$ *effectively invalidate* any further attempt at proving my conjectured implication $p^k < m \implies |2^r - t| = 1$, as detailed out in this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/406701), @mathlove?

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : I think yes since it is true that $p^k\lt m\implies (3)\ \text{or}\ (4)\implies |2^r-t|\not=1$. By the way, I think it is wrong to say that under (3) or (4), $|2^r-t|=1$ is sufficient for $p^k\lt m$ to hold since under (3) or (4), one has $|2^r-t|\not=1$ in the first place.

Comment: I did obtain, under (3) or (4), that $p^k < m|2^r - t|$, which means that $|2^r - t| = 1$ is indeed *sufficient* for $p^k < m$ to hold, @mathlove.

Comment: What I meant was that $|2^r - t| = 1 \implies |2^r - t| \neq 1$ just leads to the absolute value being not equal to $1$, and that it is *not fundamentally wrong* to assert that the equation where the absolute value equals $1$ is a *sufficient condition* for $p^k < m$, under (3) or (4), @mathlove.

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : I should have said that it is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) that under (3) or (4), $|2^r−t|=1$ is sufficient for $p^k<m$ to hold.

Comment: By the way, I invite you to post your comment that $p^k < m \implies (3) \text{ or } (4) \implies |2^r - t| \neq 1$ as an actual answer to the MO question that I linked in my comment above. Thank you, @mathlove.

Comment: No worries, @mathlove, I perfectly understood!