# On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ - Part III

Tags: number-theory, inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers, open-problem

**Preamble: This post is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4170595).**

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then we call $n$ an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must necessarily have the form $n = p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the *special prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently [Sorli](http://hdl.handle.net/10453/20034) conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  Dris conjectured that the inequality $p^k < m$ is true in his [M. Sc.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) [thesis](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), and [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) eventually produced a proof for the weaker inequality $p < m$.

Now, [recent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376268) [evidence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393738) suggests that $p^k < m$ may in fact be false.

**THE ARGUMENT**

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m$ is odd, then $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  Moreover, $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square** ([Dris and San Diego (2020)](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-4/33-38/)).

This implies that we may write
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$$
where $2^r \neq t$, $r \geq 2$, and $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

It is trivial to prove that $m \neq 2^r$ and $m \neq t$, so that we consider the following cases:

$$\text{Case (1):  } m > t > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (2):  } m > 2^r > t$$
$$\text{Case (3):  } t > m > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (4):  } 2^r > m > t$$
$$\text{Case (5):  } t > 2^r > m$$
$$\text{Case (6):  } 2^r > t > m$$

We can rule out Case **(5)** and Case **(6)**, and under Case **(1)** and Case **(2)**, we can prove that the inequality $m < p^k$ holds.

So we are now left with Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**.

Now, let us consider the quantity
$$\Delta := p^k m^2 - (m^2 - p^k) - 1 = (m^2 + 1)(p^k - 1) = (m^2 + 1)(p - 1)s(p^k).$$
Since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m^2 + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, then $\Delta$ is **not** (?) a *square*.  Note that $\Delta \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.

This implies that we may write
$$\Delta := p^k m^2 - (m^2 - p^k) - 1 = (m^2 + 1)(p^k - 1) = (m^2 + 1)(p - 1)s(p^k) = 2^u v$$
where $u \geq 2$, and $\gcd(2,v)=1$.

We thereby obtain
$$n - 1 = 2^r t + 2^u v = 2^r t + (m^2 + 1)(p - 1)s(p^k).$$

Note that
$$s(p^k) = \sigma(p^k) - p^k \equiv (k + 1) - 1 \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4.$$

We also get
$$s(p^k) = \frac{n - {2^r t} - 1}{(m^2 + 1)(p - 1)}$$
from which it follows that
$$\frac{\sigma(m^2)}{p^k} = \frac{D(m^2)}{s(p^k)} = \frac{(2m^2 - \sigma(m^2))(m^2 + 1)(p - 1)}{n - {2^r t} - 1} = \gcd(m^2, \sigma(m^2))$$
$$= p\sigma(m^2) - 2(p - 1)m^2.$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Is my proof that "$\Delta$ is **not** a square" *logically sound*?  If it is not correct, how can it be mended so as to produce a valid argument?

Comment: FYI : According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=40%28m%5E2%2B1%29%3Dn%5E2), for $p=41$ and $k=1$, one has $\Delta=40(m^2+1)$ which is a square when $m=\dfrac 12\bigg|(\sqrt{10} - 3) (19 + 6 \sqrt{10})^t)-(\sqrt{10}+3) (19 - 6 \sqrt{10})^t\bigg|$ where $t$ is a non-negative integer.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove.  Can you show that
$${10}^{375} < m = \frac{1}{2}|(\sqrt{10} - 3)(19 + 6\sqrt{10})^t - (\sqrt{10} + 3)(19 - 6\sqrt{10})^t|$$
can hold?

Comment: Yes. One has $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac 12\bigg|(\sqrt{10} - 3) (19 + 6 \sqrt{10})^t)-(\sqrt{10}+3) (19 - 6 \sqrt{10})^t\bigg|$$=\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{(19 + 6 \sqrt{10})^t}{2}\bigg|\sqrt{10}-3-(\sqrt{10}+3)\bigg(\dfrac{19 - 6 \sqrt{10}}{19+6\sqrt{10}}\bigg)^t\bigg|=+\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for that further comment, @mathlove.  If you would just post your last two comments as an actual answer, I would upvote and then accept.  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=40%28m%5E2%2B1%29%3Dn%5E2), for $p=41$ and $k=1$, one has $\Delta=40(m^2+1)$ which is a square when $$m=\frac 12\bigg|(10−\sqrt 3)(19+6\sqrt{10})^t−(10+\sqrt 3)(19−6\sqrt{10})^t\bigg|$$ where $t$ is a non-negative integer.

Also, $$10^{375}\lt m=\frac 12\bigg|(10−\sqrt 3)(19+6\sqrt{10})^t−(10+\sqrt 3)(19−6\sqrt{10})^t\bigg|$$
can hold since one has
$$\begin{align}&\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac 12\bigg|(\sqrt{10} - 3) (19 + 6 \sqrt{10})^t-(\sqrt{10}+3) (19 - 6 \sqrt{10})^t\bigg|
\\\\&=\lim_{t\to\infty}\dfrac{(19 + 6 \sqrt{10})^t}{2}\bigg|\sqrt{10}-3-(\sqrt{10}+3)\bigg(\dfrac{19 - 6 \sqrt{10}}{19+6\sqrt{10}}\bigg)^t\bigg|
\\\\&=+\infty.\end{align}$$

Comment: I removed the extra right parenthesis in the first limit formula.  I hope you do not mind, @mathlove.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Thanks :)