# On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ - Part IV

Tags: number-theory, inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers, open-problem

(Preamble:  This post is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4170595).)

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then we call $n$ an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must necessarily have the form $n = p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the *special prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently [Sorli](http://hdl.handle.net/10453/20034) conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  Dris conjectured that the inequality $p^k < m$ is true in his [M. Sc.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) [thesis](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), and [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) eventually produced a proof for the weaker inequality $p < m$.

Now, [recent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376268) [evidence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393738) suggests that $p^k < m$ may in fact be false.

**THE ARGUMENT**

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m$ is odd, then $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  Moreover, $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square** ([Dris and San Diego (2020)](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-4/33-38/)).

This implies that we may write
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$$
where $2^r \neq t$, $r \geq 2$, and $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

It is trivial to prove that $m \neq 2^r$ and $m \neq t$, so that we consider the following cases:

$$\text{Case (1):  } m > t > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (2):  } m > 2^r > t$$
$$\text{Case (3):  } t > m > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (4):  } 2^r > m > t$$
$$\text{Case (5):  } t > 2^r > m$$
$$\text{Case (6):  } 2^r > t > m$$

We can rule out Case **(5)** and Case **(6)**, and under Case **(1)** and Case **(2)**, we can prove that the inequality $m < p^k$ holds.  (For the details of the proof, we refer the interested reader to this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.13652).)

So we are now left with Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**.

Under Case **(3)**, we have:
$$(m + 2^r)(m - t) < 0$$
$$m^2 - 2^r t < m(t - 2^r)$$
$$p^k < m(t - 2^r),$$
whence we do *not* obtain a contradiction, since $t - 2^r$ is positive under this case.

Under Case **(4)**, we have:
$$(m - 2^r)(m + t) < 0$$
$$m^2 - 2^r t < m(2^r - t)$$
$$p^k < m(2^r - t),$$
whence we do *not* obtain a contradiction, since $2^r - t$ is positive under this case.

Here then is our question:

> **Will it be possible to improve on the bounds
> $$p^k < m(t - 2^r)$$
> under *Case (3)*, and
> $$p^k < m(2^r - t)$$
> under *Case (4)*?  If *YES*, can you show how?  If *NOT*, can you explain why?**

**PostScript**:  I think that both bounds may be combined as
$$p^k < m\left|{2^r - t}\right|$$
but I may be wrong.

Comment: "PostScript: I think that both bounds may be combined as $p^k < m\left|{2^r - t}\right|$ but I may be wrong" I think that you are not wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the affirmation, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: Would you mind checking out this [answer to a closely related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405222/10365), @mathlove, where I try to rule out Case **(3)**?

Comment: I also have this [other answer to that same MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/405229/10365), @mathlove.  I invite you to check it out!  =)

Comment: Apologies for the bother, @mathlove, but do you think that assuming the inequality $p^k < m$ under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)** is *equivalent* to assuming $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$?  Please advise.  Thanks!  =)

Comment: It is true that $|2^r-t|=1\implies p^k < m$, but I don't know if it is true that $p^k\lt m\implies |2^r - t|=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @mathlove!  Let me post a separate question regarding that inquiry.

Comment: I went ahead and posted a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269988) regarding my last inquiry, @mathlove.  Thank you very much for your time!  =)

Comment: Would you mind checking out my [recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4284865/28816) to that separate question I mentioned in my last comment, @mathlove?  Thank you very much for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0):

**Too long to comment:** This is not an answer to the original question, just some more thoughts that recently occurred to me, as I was pondering more on this problem.

---

We will prove the following here: Under Case **(1)** and Case **(2)**, we have
$$p^k > m\left|{2^r - t}\right|.$$

---

Under Case **(1)**: $m > t > 2^r$

$$(m - t)(m + 2^r) > 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t > m(t - 2^r) = m\left|{2^r - t}\right|$$

Under Case **(2)**: $m > 2^r > t$

$$(m - 2^r)(m + t) > 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t > m(2^r - t) = m\left|{2^r - t}\right|$$

**QED**

Answer (score 0):

**Too long to comment:** This is not really an answer, just some more thoughts that recently occurred to me, while I was pondering more on this problem.

---

As shown in the original question, we have
$$p^k < m\left|{2^r - t}\right|$$
under both Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**.

But we have the equation
$$m^2 - 2^r t = p^k.$$

This implies that we have the inequality
$$m^2 - 2^r t < m\left|{2^r - t}\right|$$
$$m^2 - m\left|{2^r - t}\right| - 2^r t < 0$$

This is a quadratic inequality, which can be solved as
$$m_1 < m < m_2$$
where
$$m_1 = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| - \sqrt{\bigg(\left|{2^r - t}\right|\bigg)^2 + 4\cdot(2^r t)}}{2} = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| - \left|{2^r + t}\right|}{2}$$
and
$$m_2 = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| + \sqrt{\bigg(\left|{2^r - t}\right|\bigg)^2 + 4\cdot(2^r t)}}{2} = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| + \left|{2^r + t}\right|}{2}.$$

Since $2^r t$ is positive, and $2^r \geq 4$, then $t$ is likewise positive.

This means that $m_2$ is nothing but
$$m_2 = \frac{(2^r + t) + \left|{2^r - t}\right|}{2} = \max(2^r,t)$$
so that
$$m < m_2 = \max(2^r,t),$$
which does *not* improve on the known upper bounds for $m$ under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**.

---

Now, let us consider the values of
$$m_1 = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| - \left|{2^r + t}\right|}{2} = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| - (2^r + t)}{2}$$
under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**.

Case **(3)**: $t > m > 2^r$
$$m_1 = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| - (2^r + t)}{2} = \frac{(t - 2^r) - (2^r + t)}{2} = -2^r,$$
implying that $m > -2^r$, which is *trivial*.

Case **(4)**: $2^r > m > t$
$$m_1 = \frac{\left|{2^r - t}\right| - (2^r + t)}{2} = \frac{(2^r - t) - (2^r + t)}{2} = -t,$$
implying that $m > -t$, which is *trivial*.