# On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ - Part V

Tags: number-theory, factoring, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers, open-problem

(**Preamble:** This post is an offshoot of this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4263930) and this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393738).)

My primary aim in this post is to compute a (*hopefully factorable*) expression for the quantity $n^2 - q^k$, if $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, $\gcd(q,n)=1$, $n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$, with $r \geq 2$, and $\gcd(2,t)=1$.  (The last GCD constraint holds because $n^2 - q^k$ is **not a square**.)

Letting
$$i(q):=\text{ index of } N \text{ at the special prime } q,$$
as defined by [Broughan et. al](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/n39/n39.pdf), then we have
$$i(q):=\frac{\sigma(N/q^k)}{q^k}=\frac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)}=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$$
whereupon we obtain
$$n^2 = i(q)\cdot\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}$$
and
$$q^k = \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{i(q)},$$
giving the difference
$$n^2 - q^k = \frac{\bigg(i(q)\bigg)^2 \cdot\sigma(q^k) - 2\sigma(n^2)}{2i(q)}.$$

Let us now try to evaluate and simplify the numerator of $n^2 - q^k$, using the following *linear combination formula* for $i(q)=\gcd(n^2,\sigma(n^2))$ from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3394489/28816):
$$i(q) = q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q - 1)n^2$$
$$\bigg(i(q)\bigg)^2 \cdot\sigma(q^k) - 2\sigma(n^2) = \bigg(q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q - 1)n^2\bigg)^2 \cdot\sigma(q^k) - 2\sigma(n^2).$$

I then tried to factor the resulting expression using WolframAlpha but was unsuccessful.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**