# On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ - Part VI

Tags: number-theory, inequality, conjectures, perfect-numbers, open-problem

(Note:  This question has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406701).)

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.

If $n$ is odd and $\sigma(n)=2n$, then we call $n$ an *odd perfect number*.  Euler proved that a hypothetical odd perfect number must necessarily have the form $n = p^k m^2$ where $p$ is the *special prime* satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Descartes, Frenicle, and subsequently [Sorli](http://hdl.handle.net/10453/20034) conjectured that $k=1$ always holds.  Dris conjectured that the inequality $p^k < m$ is true in his [M. Sc.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) [thesis](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), and [Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) eventually produced a proof for the weaker inequality $p < m$.

Now, [recent](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/376268) [evidence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393738) suggests that $p^k < m$ may in fact be false.

**THE ARGUMENT**

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.

Since $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $m$ is odd, then $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  Moreover, $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square** ([Dris and San Diego (2020)](http://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-4/33-38/)).

This implies that we may write
$$m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$$
where $2^r \neq t$, $r \geq 2$, and $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

It is trivial to prove that $m \neq 2^r$ and $m \neq t$, so that we consider the following cases:

$$\text{Case (1):  } m > t > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (2):  } m > 2^r > t$$
$$\text{Case (3):  } t > m > 2^r$$
$$\text{Case (4):  } 2^r > m > t$$
$$\text{Case (5):  } t > 2^r > m$$
$$\text{Case (6):  } 2^r > t > m$$

---

We can easily rule out Case **(5)** and Case **(6)**, as follows:

Under Case **(5)**, we have $m < t$ and $m < 2^r$, which implies that $m^2 < 2^r t$.  This gives
$$5 \leq p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < 0,$$
which is a contradiction.

Under Case **(6)**, we have $m < 2^r$ and $m < t$, which implies that $m^2 < 2^r t$.  This gives
$$5 \leq p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < 0,$$
which is a contradiction.

---

Under Case **(1)** and Case **(2)**, we can prove that the inequality $m < p^k$ holds, as follows:

Under Case **(1)**, we have:
$$(m - t)(m + 2^r) > 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t > m(t - 2^r) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

Under Case **(2)**, we have:
$$(m - 2^r)(m + t) > 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t > m(2^r - t) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

---

So we are now left with Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**.

Under Case **(3)**, we have:
$$(m + 2^r)(m - t) < 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < m(t - 2^r) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

Under Case **(4)**, we have:
$$(m - 2^r)(m + t) < 0$$
$$p^k = m^2 - 2^r t < m(2^r - t) = m\left|2^r - t\right|.$$

Note that, under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**, we actually have
$$\min(2^r,t) < m < \max(2^r,t).$$

But the condition $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$ is sufficient for $p^k < m$ to hold.

Our inquiry is:

> **QUESTION:** Is the condition $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$ also necessary for $p^k < m$ to hold, under Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**?

Note that the condition $\left|2^r - t\right|=1$ contradicts the inequality
$$\min(2^r,t) < m < \max(2^r,t),$$
under the remaining Case **(3)** and Case **(4)**, and the fact that $m$ is an integer.