# Will it be possible to compute a factored expression for $n^2 - q^k$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

Tags: number-theory, factoring, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

In what follows, we denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by
$$\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)=\sum_{d \mid x}{d},$$
and the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

If $N$ is odd and $\sigma(N)=2N$, then $N$ is called an *odd perfect number* (hereinafter abbreviated as **OPN**).  Euler proved that a hypothetical **OPN** $N$ must have the form
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the *special/Euler prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

It is currently unknown whether any **OPNs** exist.  It is widely believed that there are no **OPNs**.

---

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be a hypothetical **OPN**.

Then, since $N$ is perfect and $\gcd(q,n)=1$, and using the fact that the divisor sum $\sigma$ is *multiplicative*, we have the equation
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2 q^k n^2.$$

We can rewrite this equation as
$$n^2 = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}$$
and
$$q^k = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}.$$

Notice that
$$\frac{8}{5} < I(n^2) =  \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} < 2,$$
so that $I(n^2)$ is not an integer.  This means that
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \nmid \gcd(q^k,n^2) = 1,$$
which is expected, since
$$3 \leq \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}.$$

---

Hence, this approach does not appear to allow us to write
$$n^2 - q^k$$
in factored form.

Note that $\gcd(q,n)=1$, and that $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

We do know from [On odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ - Part VI](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4269988), however, that we can write
$$n^2 - q^k = 2^r t$$
where $2^r \neq t, r \geq 2$, and $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

Here is my inquiry:

> **QUESTION:** Will it be possible to compute a factored expression for $n^2 - q^k$, if $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$?

**PostScript:** Note that this question is related to this [other inquiry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4265002).

Comment: Of course, such a factored expression, if at all possible, would most likely be in terms of $q$, $k$, and $n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.

---

$$n^2 - q^k = \frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\cdot\Bigg(\frac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} - \frac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2}\Bigg)$$

Since $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n^2$ holds in general and $\gcd\left(q^k,\sigma(q^k)\right)=1$, then
$$\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \nmid \left(n^2 - q^k\right).$$

**Alas, this is where we get stuck!**